# Kafka on Kubernetes under containerd, liveness probe fails

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, containerd

When upgrading from k8s 1.10, using same charts, to v1.12.x, zookeeper runs, but kafka fails on liveness probe.  it simply runs:

exec [ sh -ec /usr/bin/jps | /bin/grep -q SupportedKafka ]

ret: exit 1

We have been using the confluentinc cp-kafka docker images (4.1.0, etc).

Is there some changes required, due to new use of containerd ?

Thanks!